# error occured while installing ubuntu 12.04 using Windows installer for Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 12.04, wubi

While trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using wubi on my machine which is already installed with Win7, at last it is throwing an Error Pop-up with error code 22 and also says that INVALID ARGUMENT. Following is the data from Log File

---

```
H:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
01-27 18:52 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
01-27 18:52 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
01-27 18:52 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
01-27 18:52 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
01-27 19:12 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
**01-27 19:15 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
01-27 19:15 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-27 19:15 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
01-27 19:15 ERROR  root: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 202, in copy_file
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
01-27 19:15 ERROR  TaskList: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 595, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 564, in use_cd
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'
01-27 19:15 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-27 19:15 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist**
```

---

Above is the Part of log file where it is showing error.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: See here: https://answers.launchpad.net/wubi/+question/136025  for some pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the wubi.exe installer from the CD image or as a standalone like from this link [Ubuntu Official Wubi Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), it is suggested that the installer wubi from the link above is the best option.

Comment: I had downloaded wubi.exe installer from ubuntu.com and a CD with Ubuntu 12.04 version is there in CD Rom . So it will extract files from CD Rom and at last before finalizing, its showing the error screen and quiting .

Comment: What does the error screen say? There should be no need to download the 12.04 ISO as it should detect it online and download it from the net. Have you tried this?

Comment: Did you follow this example? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows

Comment: Error screen shows "Invalid Argument " . The Log file is as show above. I do have internet connectivity, instead of downloading from internet it is accessing CD-Rom for OS.

Comment: I would place the wubi.exe file that you downloaded from the ubuntu.com website in its own folder and make sure you do not have an ubuntu 12.04 iso files the wubi script will then search the internet and download it. It should not be accessing your CDROM if there is no disk in the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues check out this wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide